# Using Excel to Find Sequences of Consecutive Dates in a Column

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a column of dates that are in the format: yyyymmdd.
An example is shown below:

```
19480110
19480111
19480115
19480119
19480124
19480130
19480131
19480201
19480204
19480209
19480210
19481225
19481226
19490212
19491210
19500108
19500208
```

I would like to be able to identify ONLY the cells that have 3 OR MORE consecutive dates. In this case, the cells with the following values would be highlighted:

```
19480130 
19480131 
19480201
```

Currently, I have a formula of the form:

```
=IF(A2=A1+1, "Match", "")
```

However, it fails to recognize instances when there is a change in the month, as in the case of this example: It only prints match next to the cell that has '19480131' in it. Is there a way to account for changes in months with the present formatting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A** starting at **A2**, in **B2** enter:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),RIGHT(A2,2))
```

and copy down.  This converts to real dates.  then in **C2** enter:

```
=B2-B1
```

and copy down

If there are two consecutive **1**'s in column **C**, we have a consecutive triplet *(at least)*.  So in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C2=1,C3=1), AND(C2=1,C1=1), AND(C4=1,C3=1)),"*","")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. Thank you so much!!! This worked like a charm. You are a lifesaver!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the date text to a date value, e.g.

```
 =IF(DATE(VALUE(LEFT(A2,4)),VALUE(MID(A2,5,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2)))=DATE(VALUE(LEFT(A1,4)),VALUE(MID(A1,5,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)))+1, "Match", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `=IF(A2=A1+1, "Match", IF(AND(OR(MOD(A1, 100) = 31, MOD(A1, 100) = 30, MOD(A1, 100) = 29, MOD(A1, 100) = 28), MOD(A2, 100) = 1), "Match", ""))`

Having said that, there is a caveat that if you have Jan 28 and then Feb 01 it will say that is consecutive where you know it is not. If you want something that doesn't have that issue, I can code that.